Are two notions of power-associativity equivalent for loops?
According to Groupprops, a magma $X$ is called power-associative if for every element $x\in X$ there exists a sequence $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $X$ such that $x^1=x$ and $x^m\cdot x^n=x^{m+n}$ for every positive integer numbers $n,m\in\mathbb N$.
On the other hand, by Groupprops a loop $X$ is called power-associative if for every element $x\in X$ there exists a sequence $(x^n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ of elements of $X$ such that $x^1=x$ and $x^m\cdot x^n=x^{m+n}$ for every integer numbers $n,m\in\mathbb Z$.
It is clear that every power-associative loop is a power-associative magma.
Question 1. Is a loop $X$ power-associative if it is power-associative as a magma?
The question actually asks where the two notions of power-associativity are equivalent for loops?
It is easy to see that every power-associative loop $X$ has two-sided inverses. The latter means that for every $x\in X$ there exists a unique element $x^{-1}\in X$ such that $x\cdot x^{-1}=e=x^{-1}\cdot x$, where $e$ is the identity of the loop $X$.
Question 2. Is a loop power-associative if it has two-sided inverses and is a power-associative magma?
